# Steam white bars

Tags: steam

I have this issue with steam. When I open it, it opens normally but pretty much all of the text is white bars. I tried installing it again, tried using windows version with wine but none of these does not work. I'm using a Dell C640.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot (you can use https://imgur.com )

Comment: i added link :)

Comment: ok... what graphics are you using (`sudo lshw -C display`), and do any errors show when it is run from terminal (probably the `steam` command).

Comment: looks to be same when opening it from terminal, graphics: Mobility Radeon 7500